# get para valor entero ?,y las comillas

Tags: java

queria preguntarles como hago para tomar un valor entero, estoy trabajando con SQL Workbeanch, y el tema es que quiero saber como tomar el valor con el metodo get, y tambien como declarar el tema de las comillas para un valor entero en sql, ya que vi que string son "", y int no tengo idea como es, estoy atascado aca, desde ya gracias!, dejo un poco de codigo para que me entiendan a que me refiero.<

```
// Aca quiero saber como pedir un valor entero, probe getParseInt pero no me aparece, quisiera saber como paso esos datos enteros, a mi bd que estan declarados int //
try {
            Conexion objCon = new Conexion();
            Connection conn = objCon.getConexion();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO prueba (id,num) VALUES (?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, txtCodigo.getText());
            ps.setString(2, txtNombre.getText());


            ps.execute();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Producto Guardado");
            Object[] fila = new Object[4];
            fila[0] = txtCodigo.getText();
            fila[1] = txtNombre.getText();

            modelo.addRow(fila);

            limpiar();

//Boton modificar de mi proyect. Quiero saber como a número lo pongo en valor ENTERO en sql , ya que me dice que error de '', y no entiendo como es para declarar un valor entero, se que String es "", pero entero googlee y nose como és.

   ResultSetMetaData rsMd = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
            int cantidadColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();

            modelo.addColumn("id");
            modelo.addColumn("num");
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! los valores numericos en sql van sin ningun tipo de comillas.. a eso te referis?

Comment: Claro y el tema de los gets para recibir o tomar valores enteros!

Comment: Ni idea qué es `SQL Workbeanch` :(

Answer (score 0):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Si revisas la interfaz `PreparedStatement`, verás que tiene un [método `setInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt-int-int-):

> Establece el parámetro designado al valor `int` de Java dado. El
>   controlador lo convierte en un valor `INTEGER` de SQL cuando lo envía
>   a la base de datos.

Ahora bien, el valor que se le pasa a ese método debe ser un entero. Supongamos que la columna `id` es numérica, dado que `txtCodigo.getText()` devolvería una cadena, tendrías que convertir ese valor a entero antes de pasarlo al objeto `ps`, sería algo así:

```
int mId = Integer.parseInt(txtCodigo.getText());
ps.setInt(1, mId);
```

Esta es una explicación sencilla. Ahora bien, convendría proteger tu código y hacer evaluaciones como asegurarte que `txtCodigo.getText()` no arroje valores nulos, o no se escriban en él valores que no se puedan convertir a números. Imagina que alguien escribe una  `A` donde debería ir un número... Todo eso debe ser controlado (muy probablemente a otro nivel, por ejemplo aplicando controles en ese campo de texto para que sólo acepte números), pero ese es ya otro asunto.

Comment: Muchas Gracias !, intentare convertir el dato de string a int , y el tema de desclarar las comillas ,un valor entero en sql?

Comment: @JuanHerrera no entiendo cuál es tu dificultad en ese punto que comentas de las comillas. En la segunda parte de tu código se intuye una manipulación extraña que no se entiende qué finalidad tiene. En todo caso, creo que son dos temas diferentes y que deberías plantearlo en otra pregunta. En la 2ª parte del código se ve como si intentases leer un conjunto de resultados sin saber cuál es la consulta que obtiene esos resultados.